# How to avoid AG-Grid empty row lines?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

[image: ag-grid contains empty row lines]

As you can see, AG-Grid displays empty row lines.
It happens in several tables, and I do not know why.

In this case I try to load data with :

```
const loadPaginated = async ({ success, request: { startRow = 0, endRow = 100 } }) => {
  const { content, totalElements } = await query({ startRow, endRow }); // content: Array(23), totalElements: 23
  success({ rowData: content, rowCount: totalElements });
};

<AgGridReact
  serverSideDatasource={{ getRows: onLoadPaginated }}
  serverSideStoreType="partial"
  rowModelType="serverSide"
  pagination
  paginationAutoPageSize
  columnDefs={columnDefs}
/>
```

Environment info:

- ag-grid-community 26.2.1,
- ag-grid-enterprise 26.2.1,
- ag-grid-react 26.2.0,
- I have got AG-Grid licensed

I tried to purge data, I tried to refresh the view, I tried to use `rowData` instead of `serverSideDatasource`, it still does not work.

Can you help me to display these rows again?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you dont have unique row ids. On you screenshot I see the same ID.

Try to specify `getRowId` callback, which will provide a unique ID for every row.

```
<AgGridReact
  ...
  getRowId={(params) => params.data.uniqueId}
/>
```

or compose ID using different fields to achieve unique value per row.

```
<AgGridReact
  ...
  getRowId={(params) => `${params.data.id}_${params.data.name}_${params.data.something}`}
/>
```